# How to install sharepoint development kit labs

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I tried running one of the .bat files with CMD.

The first line it works

```
powershell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"
powershell -Command "& {.\SetupLabxx.ps1}" -NoExit
```

pause

The second line gives me this exception

> The term '.\SetupLabxx.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function , script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a pat h was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. At line:1 char:20 + & {.\SetupLabxx.ps1 <<<< } -NoExit +
>   CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (.\SetupLabxx.ps1:String) [], Co
>   mmandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the commands (use full path to script):

```
powershell.exe -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File c:\SetupLabxx.ps1
```